# Can you offer salah while someone is sitting next to you?

Tags: sharia, salat

I heard from somewhere that one can not pray while someone is in front (which is obviously not allowed) , or even if someone is sitting next to you. I often pray while my colleges are sitting next to me on a chair. Is that alright? or do i need to find another spot?

Comment: IIRC it is OK if they sit on your left side or behind you... if they sit on your right side it is not recommended... Allah knows best.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly OK to pray when someone is sitting and even lying beside you. The only recommendation that I am aware of is pray in a place where no one can pass in front of you. This does not annuls the prayer as some people *might* think.

[Narrated Aisha (RA)- Sahih Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8#158) Passing infront of of someone praying does not break salat, unless it is a dog or donkey.

> The things which annul the prayers were mentioned before me. They
>   said, "Prayer is annulled by a dog, a donkey and a woman (if they pass
>   in front of the praying people)." I said, "You have made us (i.e.
>   women) dogs. I saw the Prophet () praying while I used to lie in my
>   bed between him and the Qibla. Whenever I was in need of something, I
>   would slip away. for I disliked to face him."

[This hadith from Aisha (RA)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/8#155) says, the prophet used to pray in the room when she would be laying. This is enough to deduce, praying with someone sitting or laying in the room is totally valid. The person who is in the room should respect the person who is praying though. They should not do anything awkward. If they do, you might well want to excuse yourself and pray in separate room.

Comment: @Arbaaz why would you report this answer?

Comment: This H*adīth has been rejected by the learned among the companions of the Prophet (sws). The reason is that it offends common sense and does not conform to basic religious teachings.
http://www.monthly-renaissance.com/issue/query.aspx?id=63

Comment: @Arbaaz the answer in your link quotes my hadiths to prove that the mentioned hadith in the question is wrong. That is prayer is not broken if a woman passes in front. Or Am I wrong here?

Comment: No you are not wrong, i did not read your answer well, my apologies.

Comment: Man! Why the down vote!!! It's a good answer.
+1 for compensation. :)